# Append Row to Google Spreadsheet-->TypeError: keys must be a string

Tags: python, google-sheets, row, typeerror

I am trying to append a row to a google spreadsheet but get an error. Usually it works but now it says:

```
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Does anyone know what it means?

Here is my code and a print of all the datatypes I try to insert. Is there a problem with numpy types or boolean for spreadsheets?

```
for e in range(experiments):
    #types: <class 'int'>,<class 'str'>,<class 'numpy.str_'>,<class 'float'>,<class 'int'>,<class 'int'>,<class 'numpy.float64'>,<class 'numpy.float64'>,<class 'numpy.float64'>,<class 'int'>,<class 'collections.defaultdict'>,<class 'int'>,<class 'int'>,<class 'float'>,<class 'bool'>

    insertRow=[training,gameList[e],stateList[e], eps, experiments,timesteps,min_rewardList[e],maxRewList[e],total_rewList[e],currentMaxXList[e],maxXList[e],frames_stack,mb_size,learning_rate,completed_levelList[e]]
    sheet.append_row(insertRow)
```

Comment: First check if all the keys are strings and then append it to the sheet